# Где допущена ошибка в преобразование в Python?

Tags: python

помогите понять где ошибка. Нужно переменную russian_native которая находится в float преобразовать в int 
Сам код после преобразования :

```
russian_native_millions = 153.9
russian_native = russian_native_millions * 1000000
print(russian_native)
print(type(russian_native))
russian_native = int(russian_native_millions * 1000000)
print(russian_native)
print(type(russian_native))

153900000.0
<class 'float'>
153900000
<class 'int'>
```

Система пишет что код работает, но либо не выполняет задачи или выполняет лишние. 
В чем ошибка ?

Comment: А не должно ли значение `153.9` стать `154`?

Comment: напишите в примере, что вы хотите получить

Comment: Нет, значение должно остаться 159.9

Comment: Задание было russian_native из float переименовать в int . По строке кода все прошло. Но кто составлял тех задание написал "код работает , но не выполняет задачи или выполняет лишние, перепишите код иначе" .А как иначе я понять не могу.

Comment: Приведите пример вывода буквально как в задании. Возможно или тип не требуется выводить, или исходное значение, или еще что-то.

Answer (score 0):

Так? Если нет, поясните подробней что нужно.

```
russian_native_millions = 153.9
russian_native = int(russian_native_millions * 1000000)
print(russian_native)
```